# Spring's URIComponentsBuilder converts colon (:) for port number into slash (/)

Tags: spring-web

In a test, I am injecting an example URL with a colon for a port number ("http://example.com:port") into my configuration, which is then used by my production code to construct a `UriComponentsBuilder` which ultimately creates a URI String.

However, that colon character is being converted into a forward slash by the `UriComponentsBuilder`, as demonstrated in this MCVE:

```
@Test
public void portNumberFromHttpUrl() {
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://example.com:port");

    String uriString = builder.toUriString();

    assertThat(uriString).isEqualTo("http://example.com:port");
}
```

This test fails as follows:

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure:
>   Expected :"http://example.com:port"
>   Actual   :"http://example.com/port"

Why is the `:` being converted to a `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MCVE helped me answer this myself almost immediately, but I'll leave the question here because I couldn't find the same question here or anywhere else online, and I guess it might save someone else some time:

It seems that `UriComponentsBuilder` recognises that a port should be a number, so this (more realistic) case passes:

```
@Test
public void portNumberFromHttpUrl() {
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://example.com:123");

    String uriString = builder.toUriString();

    assertThat(uriString).isEqualTo("http://example.com:123");
}
```

From a little more investigation it seems that it puts a `/` before the first non-numeric character that it encounters after a `:`, so:

`http://example.com:a123` -> `http://example.com/a123`
`http://example.com:12a3` -> `http://example.com:12/a3`
`http://example.com:123a` -> `http://example.com:123/a`

Not immediately obvious, but makes sense, I guess.